# Cannot override to_String because of an integer in C++

Tags: c++, tostring, virtual-functions

I have an Employee class that has several subclasses. I want to override the function to_String in my super class and all subclasses, but I cannot get it to work because of an integer in the super class:

```
class Employee{
public:
    Employee(...){
        ...
    }
    virtual ~Employee(){
        ...
    }
    virtual string to_String(){
        string s = stringstream(this->someInteger);
        return s;
    }
    virtual string profession(){
        ...
    }
private:
    int someInteger;
};
```

I have here the function "virtual string to_String(){...} where I'm trying to return some integer in string format. However, when I try to compile this, it gives me the error message "invalid conversion from 'int' to 'std::ios_base::openmode {aka std::_Ios_Openmode}' [fpremissive].

I have also tried to make a get-function for the integer, which also doesn't solve the problem.

However, I tried to take the problem from another perspective, and drop the to_String function and instead use a get-function to get the integer. But my problem then is that I cannot access the get-functions of the sub-classes, like the "getSomeString()" in this sub-class:

```
class Engineer : public Employee{
public:
    Engineer(...):Employee(...){

    }
    ~Engineer(){
        ...
    }
    string profession(){
        return "someProfession";
    }
    string getSomeString(){
        return this->someString;
    }
    ...
private:
    string someString;

};
```

I then try to access the getSomeString() function in the main function:

```
   fout << employees[i]->getSomeInteger(); //THIS WORKS!
   if(employees[i]->profession() == "someProfession"){
       fout << employees[i]->getSomeString(); //but this doesnt work
   }
```

I then get an error message saying 'class Employee' has no member named 'getSomeString'.

I therefore tried to cast employee[i] so that I would be able to access it stacily as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326186/how-to-call-child-method-from-a-parent-pointer-in-c). Which also didn't work..

My question now is; how do I get this to work? What am I doing wrong? And which of these versions to handle the problem would be better in this occation, or am I doing everything completely wrong?

Comment: Is `getSomeString` supposed to override `to_String`? They have different names! `Employee` doesn't have a `getSomeString` function, as the error says.

Comment: "I have here the function "virtual string to_String(){...} where I'm trying to return some integer in string format. However, when I try to compile this, it gives me the error message "invalid conversion from 'int' to 'std::ios_base::openmode {aka std::_Ios_Openmode}' [fpremissive]."

Yes, pay attention to that error and figure out what's going on.  The problem is when you're meaning to cast an integer to a string, you're invoking a stringstream contructor with an integer.  This is not what you're intending to do.  Fix the string conversion.

Comment: How do you mean I need to fix the string conversion? What's wrong with the string conversion as shown in the code?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
string s = stringstream(this->someInteger);
```

use

```
string s = std::to_string(this->someInteger);
```

Comment: Well that is a problem (along with the fact they're doing `return "s";` instead of `return s;`), but it's not the reason they're getting the error.

Comment: @Joseph Mansfield The error message is invalid conversion from 'int' to 'std::ios_base::openmode {aka std::_Ios_Openmode}'

Comment: Not sure how the "" around the s sneaked in. I have edited the post. I have tried to use std::to_String but it says to_String is not a member of 'std'.

Comment: @user1608638 The correct name of the function is to_string not to_String

Comment: @user1608638 std::to_string() requires С++11 compatible compiler.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Oh sorry, I'm going crazy.